# Coq list sorting practices & sortBy?

Tags: sorting, coq

What is the equivalent of Haskell's [sortBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) in Coq?

In general, I find the Coq standard library around sorting confusing.

I would have hoped for some "axiomatisation" of a sorted list, and the the availability of different sorts, to which I can provide an ordering function.

However, this does not seem to be the case.

- [There is a theory of a "Sorted list"](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sorting.Sorted.html), which uses a relation `Variable R : A -> A -> Prop.`
  , but there are no *restrictions* on this `R`. I would have expected it to be an ordering, but no such thing exists.
- There is another file with a "[mergesort implementation](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sorting.Mergesort.html#Sort)", which needs a new module to be passed.
- There is no "higher level" version which provides helpers such as `sortBy`.

Is there some implementation of `sortBy` I can use, or do I need to create this manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MergeSort module](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Sorting.Mergesort.html) in the Coq standard library does what you need. It works like `sortBy` in Haskell except that instead of passing an ordering function and obtaining the specialized sort, you pass a module that encapsulates the ordering function along with the proof that this function is total. See the example at the bottom of the module documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the Coq standard library, the [Mathetical Components library](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp) also has an implementation of merge sort.  It is called `sort`, and it lives in the module `mathcomp.path`.  Its signature is `forall T : Type, (T -> T -> bool) -> list T -> list T`, which is closer to the original `sortBy`.